Segment date : start and end date
I have a Power BI report that includes a date segment visual based on a 'creationDate' column (in the 'Order' table) of date type. In the visual, the segment displays two dates: 'StartDate' and 'EndDate'.
I set startDate to 01/01/24 (currentYear)
I need when i display a page, the enddate   always be set to the previous day ( currentDay -1) and
Thank you in advance for your help.
Djam75
Use Dax to assign EndData to DAY-1, but the visuel is not filter on column creationDate in table Order

You can create a new column with date for Yesterday.

do you mean that you have date slicer and want to set it from 2024/1/1 to yesterday?

Thank you, Ryan, for your interest in my problem.
I have a date slicer (segment) with fields: startDate and endDate. I need the endDate to be set to yesterday's date when the page is displayed.
Sorry if this is not clear, English is not my native language;-)

it's ok, English is not my native language,either. could you pls provide some sample data and expected output?
